# How to optimally preserve the text in a mysql field or php variable?

Tags: php, mysql, diff

I am using php/mysql, and want to preserve the text that already exists in a field, making sure any changes that come in are appended (only).

For example, if the text field in mysql contains "original text 123", and the php script has a new text of "this is new text and original text", I need to make sure I do not loose the "123" from the original text.    The new stored value should be  "this is new text and original text 123".

I was thinking I could use a [php diff library](https://github.com/nuxodin/diff_match_patch-php#readme), but that might be overkill, or possibly there is a better option.

In most cases, I will be receiving in changes such as  "this is new text and original text 123", so I would need a way to compare that "original text 123" is present at the end of the incoming change, meaning I can accept the change.   However, the change after that might be "the is new text 2 and original text 123".  In this case, I need to look at the existing text, and combine the incoming text, which would result in "this is new text 2 this is new text and original text 123", so I dont think I can do a simple compare?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that new text may contain part, all or none of old text, and if any old text is present it may be anywhere inside of the new text? I think you might find it easiest to store each text version separately rather than trying to do a diff to figure out how to update.

Comment: I ended up implemented the diff logic, which IS working, but there are some issues with it.  It becomes complicated if someone ever has to modify the text in any way.     I do think your approach to store the text separately makes sense, either storing different versions, or actually store the appends as separate records.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a custom string formatting, according to your application needs, I suggest you to get the string from mysql, then to perform a manual check in your string, looking for searched string and formatting it according to your needs, then update the record in your mysql DB. All this can be done inside your php script.

This is a sample, but it may be different according to your need:
Note:this sample suppose you call the php page from a webpage that supplies 2 variables: userId and the description to be write. the php page suppose to write on a db where the field userId is the key of the table, and the only field to write is named description

addData.php

```
 <?php
 //first of all define a function to open db and get your data
  function searchIdOnDb($id)
  {
   //connect to your database
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
   //specify database
   mysql_select_db("yourDBname") or die;
   //Build SQL Query
   $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);        
   $query = "select * from yourDBtable where userId ='" . $id . "'";
   $queryResult=mysql_query($query);
   return $queryResult;
  }
  //then define a function to update your DB record
  function setRecordOnDb($id, $description)
  {
   //the connection will be still active, then it is not needed to redo it 
   $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);        
   $description = mysql_real_escape_string($description);        
   if ($description=="") $description=" ";
   $query="UPDATE yourDBtable SET description='" . $description . "' WHERE userId='" . $id . "'";    
   $queryResult=mysql_query($query);
   return $queryResult;
  }   

  //ok, we are ready to start. first of all get your variable from the webpage
  $me=$_GET["userID"];//get user id
  $description=$_GET["description"];//get data to write
  //if no data, exit
  if ($me==null)
  {
   die;
  }

  //if no data, exit
  if ($description==null)
  {
   die;
  }

  //search in db
  $result=searchIdOnDb($me);
  $numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);
  if ($numrows == 0) { //if user is not in the db exit
   die;
  } else { 
   //the user is in the db, let's generate new description and update it
   //get description from the record
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   $originalDescription= $row["description"] ;
   //here compare your string description with the string originalString in order
   //to obtain the newDescription string
   //just for test i will append the two strings, but you can make your search inside the strings and format it according to your needs
   $newDescription=$originalDescription . " " . $description;
   //update record
   $setRecord  = setRecordOnDb($me, $newDescription);

  }

  if ($setRecord==FALSE ) {
   //error during write, send me email 
   $to = "yourEmail@yourProvider.com";
   $subject = "Error in file addData.php";
   $body = "Variables: \n me=" . $me . " \n newDescription=" . $newDescription .  " \n originalDescription=" . $originalDescription . " \n description=" . $description ;
   mail($to, $subject, $body);
   die;
  }else{
   //write ok, return ok
   die("ok");
  }

 ?>
```

Comment: Your approach sounds correct, if you have sample code, that would be great to see, thanks.

Comment: @ScottSzretter here it is. look at it.

Comment: note that the mysql_ function set has been deprecated.  Use mysqli or pdo functions.

Comment: you're right girl, even if my answer was not centered on how to read/write on a db

Comment: it looks like you are appending the incoming text to the existing text already in the database.   this is close, but not quite what I am looking for.    the incoming text will in most cases already contain the existing text.   So I do not want to duplicate that existing text.   your example works in the case that the incoming text does not contain the existing text.